# Saving picked photo to a local file using file picker

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am developing a windows 8 store app, I need to let the user to pick a photo and save it to a local folder,
I already managed the saving method in a JSON file, and I know how to work with picker

```
       FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
            openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
            openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
            StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
```

is it possible to add the picked photo to the Assets folder to be permanently there ? if yes, please help, if no, please help :D
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, the Assets folder (assuming you mean the default folder you typically get with a Windows Store project) is part of the application package and read only.  Essentially you can only read from URLS preceded by `ms-appx://`

You can save to local storage (`ms-appdata:///local/`) and it will be persistent there as well (unless you explicitly remove it).

The following line after your code will save to the top level of local storage

```
await file.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder)
```

Use [CreateFolderAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.createfolderasync.aspx) or [GetFolderAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.getfolderasync.aspx) if you want to store to a folder not directly at the root of your application data.